# JSON Provider builds wrong String field, when value is 'true' or 'false'

Tags: json, rest, jaxb, cxf

I have a problem. Could you please help me.
I have an application: CXF+Spring+JAXB+REST. And I try to generate Response using `JSONProvider` class
There is a bean class:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Foo {
@XmlElement
private String bar;
}
```

When I set to the field value:

```
setBar("true")
```

or

```
setBar("false");
```

JSONProvider returns to me:

```
"bar":false
```

But, I expect

```
"bar":"false"
```

Because I use **String** type. What should I do with that?

Comment: Thank you for answer. But, may be there is another way? I don't want change JSON Provider on another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The JAXB (JSR-222) specification does not cover JSON-binding.  In a REST/JAX-RS context it is up to the provider to apply the JAXB mapping rules to a JSON representation.  There are 3 different approaches that are being used today:

1. Use a JAXB implementation with a library like [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/).  Jettison implements the StAX interfaces but interprets JSON.  The advantage of this approach is that it can be used with any JAXB implementation to produce/consume JSON, the disadvantage of this approach is that Jettison does not have enough information to do a perfect JSON representation.  Jettison receives the String `"true"` without knowing what the corresponding Java type was, so it decides to represent it as a JSON boolean, since it is probably the desired output most of the time.
2. REST/JAX-RS implementation leverages a specific JAXB implementation to produce JSON.  This approach is similar to the first, except that the REST/JAX-RS provider makes proprietary calls to the JAXB provider to make more educated guesses to what the JSON representation should be.
3. The JAXB implementation provides the JSON-binding implementation.  Currently EclipseLink MOXy is the only JAXB implementation to support JSON-binding.

**MOXy EXAMPLE**

***Root***

Below is a domain object with `String` and `boolean` fields.  I've also added fields annotated with `@XmlSchemaType` which can be used to override the default representation.

```
package forum11145933;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    String barString;

    boolean barBoolean;

    @XmlSchemaType(name="boolean")
    String barStringWithXmlTypeBoolean;

    @XmlSchemaType(name="string")
    boolean barBooleanWithXmlTypeString;

}
```

***jaxb.properties***

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

***Demo***

The following code demonstrates how to marshal the domain object to JSON.  Note that there are no compile time dependencies on MOXy.

```
package forum11145933;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.barString = "true";
        root.barBoolean = true;
        root.barStringWithXmlTypeBoolean = "true";
        root.barBooleanWithXmlTypeString = true;

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

***Output***

The following is the output from running the `Demo` code.  Note how the `boolean` and `String` properties are written out correctly.  Also notice how the use of the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation allows us to marshal a `boolean` as a `String` and vice versa.

```
{
   "root" : {
      "barString" : "true",
      "barBoolean" : true,
      "barStringWithXmlTypeBoolean" : true,
      "barBooleanWithXmlTypeString" : "true"
   }
}
```

**MOXy & JAX-RS**

MOXy includes `MOXyJsonProvider` which can be used to enable MOXy as the JSON provider in your JAX-RS environment:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Comment: Thank you. but how can I use it? What should I write in my Spring config file here:     'code'<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider">
        <property name="serializeAsArray" value="true"/>
        <property name="arrayKeys" ref="jsonKeys"/>

        <property name="convention" value="mapped"/>
        <property name="produceMediaTypes" ref="jsonTypes"/>
        <property name="consumeMediaTypes" ref="jsonTypes"/>
        <property name="ignoreNamespaces" value="true"/>
        <property name="writeXsiType" value="false"/>
    </bean>'code'